# How to analyse memory consumption of an object using jprofiler of jrat?

Tags: java, maven, garbage-collection, testng

Now i wrote one maven testng testcase that testcase publishes 1000000 messages for that  it takes 20gb memory.manually i called Runtime.getRuntime().gc() but it didnt help me.so anyone guide me how to run jprofiler or jRat to find memory usage

Comment: sidenote: lakh is not an internationally recognized unit. I would recommend SI prefixes or scientific notation if you want to communicate on an international platform.

Comment: Okay i will update it.